# IO operator overloading error

Tags: c++, io, operator-overloading

In .h file

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream &os,const object &);
```

In .cpp file

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream &os,const object &mono)
{
    os << mono.coef<<" *X^"<<mono.degree;
    return os;      
}
```

Errors I am getting:

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'
>   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ostream'
>   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int 
>   error C2805: binary 'operator <<' has too few parameters

I've checked every IO overloading tutorial I can found yet I cannot fix this.

EDIT: adding std:: fixed every error except "> error C2805: binary 'operator <<' has too few parameters  "
I dont know what that means

EDIT2: declaring function as a friend solved this.
thanks everyone!

Comment: where is object defined?

Comment: Sounds like `ostream` and `object` both need namespace qualification.  The former would be `std::ostream` (make sure you have `#include <ostream>`) and the latter depends on where `object` is declared in your codebase.

Comment: If `ostream` is unknown, you probably missed including `fstream` or `iostream`.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Those will both include `<ostream>` but there is no reason to include them just to get `std::ostream`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ostream` without qualifying it with namespace `std::`

Use

`std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os,const object& mono)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed `friend` keyword.

And I recommend you official documentaion: 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

And also you missed `using namespace std;` or `std::ostream&`.

I hope you this answer will help your problem.